# Correctly mock a service method which returns a javax.mail.Message

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have an `EmailScanner.java` class which has

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customClient")
private EmailClient client; //EmailClient is interface
```

I am trying to write a test for above class and mocking the client as shown below.

```
    @InjectMocks
    private EmailScanner emailScanner;

    @Mock
    @Qualifier("customClient")
    private EmailClient client;
```

in the client, I have a method that reads and returns an Email. `client.fetchEmail(folderName)`.

I have written `Mockito.doReturn(getSampleMessage()).when(client).fetchEmail(Mockito.anyString());`.
getSampleMessage() reads .eml file from disk and convert it into Mail message, on running i am getting null message. Is there anything i am missed on or doing wrong here?

Comment: are you sure your `getSampleMessage` is returning valid object?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of EmailClient? I see that you are using @Qualifier, Mockito wires by type and then by name. Make sure the the mocked EmailClient that is returning the null message is the same one you used for mocking.